# Gravar valor de uma combobox ao fazer Upload de arquivos?

Tags: php, javascript, upload, combobox

Boa tarde. Comecei essa semana numa empresa de desenvolvimento em PHP. Preciso incluir uma combobox numa página que faz o upload de arquivos. O upload já funciona e vem sendo utilizado.

** Gostaria de auxílio para gravar o valor selecionado na combobox na mesma tabela dos arquivos (que o cliente escolheu para fazer o upload). Esta combobox mostra a "Categoria do Arquivo" e servirá para classificar as imagens/documentos do cliente.

arquivos.php   // Arquivo que contém a combobox e também o botão para fazer o upload dos arquivos.

```html
<div class="form-group"> Categoria do Arquivo
        <form name="formCatArq" id="formCatArq" method="post" >
          <select class="form-control" style="width:40%" name="arqcat_codigo" id="arqcat_codigo"  >
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Selecione a Categoria do Arquivo</option>
            <?php            
 //CARREGA LISTA DE CATEGORIAS           
$sql_gru = "select * from arquivos_categorias $sql_cat where arqcat_ativo ='S'  order by arqcat_titulo asc ";
$qry_gru = mysql_query($sql_gru);       
if (mysql_num_rows($qry_gru) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_gru)) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['arqcat_codigo']?>" <? if ($marqcat_codigo == $row['arqcat_codigo']) {echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> <?php echo $row['arqcat_titulo']; ?> </option>
            <?php }
}?>
          </select>
          <label>
            <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" value="Filtrar sua busca:"  />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
     
// Botão para realizar o "Upload"
      <div id="mulitplefileuploader_arquivos">Upload</div>
```

Index.php  // contém script para pegar o valor da combobox e na sequência chama a função "envia_valor" na tentativa de carregar o valor da combobox junto com a função do upload.  Estou tentando enviar a variável "$arqcat" junto com o parâmetro "url:" da variável "settings_arq", mas este valor não chega na página "upload_arquivos.php" que efetua a inserção no banco.

```js
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#arqcat_codigo').change(function(){
       var tip = $("#arqcat_codigo").val();
       if (($('#arqcat_codigo').val() == '-1') || (tip == '-1')) 
       {
            alert('Selecione a Categoria do Arquivo');
         
        }
        else {
    envia_valor(tip);
   }
    });
});
</script> 

<script> 
function envia_valor(tip) {
  $arqcat = tip;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  // alert($arqcat);
var settings_arq = {
   url: "upload_arquivos.php?cod=<?=$codigo?>&usucatcod=<?=$usucat?>&arqcatcodigo=<?=$arqcat?>",
     method: "POST",
     fileName: "myfile",
     multiple: true,
     showProgress: true,
     showStatusAfterSuccess: true,
     dragDropStr: "<span><b>Selecione os arquivos para upload23332</b></span>",
     onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
     {
      $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload realizado com sucesso</font>");
      location.reload();
     },
     onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
     {  
      $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Falha no upload</font>");
     }
    }
    $("#mulitplefileuploader_arquivos").uploadFile(settings_arq);
});
};
</script>
```

upload_arquivos.php // recebe os parâmetros e gera o sql.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
 $ret = array();
 $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
   {
    
     if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
     {
          
   $arquivo = $_FILES["myfile"];
   $nome_temp = $arquivo["tmp_name"];
   $nome_arquivo =  $cod . "-" . $arquivo["name"];
   $nome_arquivo = str_replace(' ', '', $nome_arquivo);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $nome_arquivo);
                 $ret[$arquivo]= $output_dir.$arquivo;
   $sql = "insert into arquivos (usu_codigo, arqcat_codigo, usucat_codigo, arq_legenda, arq_arquivo, arq_data, arq_imagem)  values($cod, '$arqcatcodigo', '$usucatcod', '$arquivo[name]','$nome_arquivo',curdate(),'N')";
   $post = mysql_query($sql);
   $codigo = mysql_insert_id();
   $ext = strxchr($nome_arquivo, ".", 1, 1);
   $ext = substr(strtolower($ext[1]),1);
    if ($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg' || $ext=='png') {
     GerarImagens($nome_arquivo, 200, 'thumb_');
     GerarImagens($nome_arquivo, 227, 'gal_');
     $sql2 = "update arquivos set arq_imagem='S' where arq_codigo=$codigo";
     $qry2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    }
   
     }
     
    }  
    echo json_encode($ret); 
}
?>
```

Comment: "`<div id="mulitplefileuploader_arquivos">Upload</div>`" Isso é um botão?

Comment: Eu não escrevi o código, estou adaptando a combobox no formulário. Eu não sei lhe explicar, mas essa div faz o botão do upload (acho que deve ser Jquery). Não existe um botão com input, somente isso. O nome dessa div aparece na página index.php, onde são atribuídos alguns parâmetros que serão enviados à página upload_arquivos.php (que vai executar o sql).
Eu estou tentando passar o valor da combobox na função "settings_arq " na página index, para que o mesmo seja adicionado no sql e gravar no momento que o usuário escolhe o arquivo para upload.

Comment: Foi malz ae , eu vi ali o jquery faz o botão... tô vendo aqui vê se consigo ajudar

Comment: Se você descomentar o `alert($arqcat);`, ele mostra a opção selecionada?

Comment: Sim.. até esse momento o alert exibe a variável. Mas quando tento chamar dentro da "var settings_arq" ele não chega na página destino. 
Tentei enviar a variável $arqcat através da linha   `insira o código aqui`url: "upload_arquivos.php?cod=<?=$codigo?>&usucatcod=<?=$usucat?>&arqcatcodigo=<?=$arqcat?>",     , mas não funcionou. As variáveis $usucat e $codigo são passadas no momento que o usuário clica no menu para tela de uploads.

Comment: Tentei enviar a variável $arqcat através da linha  `url: "upload_arquivos.php?cod=<?=$codigo?>&usucatcod=<?=$usucat?>&arqcatcodigo=<?=$arqcat?>",`  , mas não funcionou. As variáveis $usucat e $codigo são passadas no momento que o usuário clica no menu para tela de uploads.

Comment: Mas dá alguma mensagem de erro? Depois que fizer o teste clica em exibir código fonte e vê se dá algum erro?

Comment: Tendo em vista que não estou conseguindo enviar o valor da combobox junto com a variável "settings_arq", estou pensando em deixar a combobox e após o upload o usuário clica em um novo botão que vai fazer a inserção(alteração) naquele registro da imagem/arquivo no banco e gravar no campo correspondente o valor da combobox. Mas fico correndo um risco de que o usuário saia da tela sem registrar a categoria do arquivo(combobox).

Comment: Cara isso deve ser um errinho bobo... eu tenho um form aqui semelhante...Mas não aconselho vc a desistir, a não ser que não exista outro caminho... Tenta começar um processo igual a esse do 0, com o mínimo de informações possíveis ...parte por parte...

Comment: Bom dia  MagicHat. A função "envia_valor" recebe o valor da combobox, pois fui usando o alert pra testar. O problema é que eu preciso enviar esse valor junto com a variável "var_settings"  que é gerada pelo upload do arquivo.  Essa variável envia os dados para a página upload_arquivos, onde tem o sql para inserção. Você conhece alguma maneira de inserir um valor da uma variável, dentro dos atributos de outra variável ?

Comment: Tentei enviar o valor através da url, mas das várias formas que testei, nenhuma funcionou. Tentei fazer "valor: $arqcat,"  dentro dos atributos da variável "settings_arq", mas também não deu certo.

Comment: é realmente necessário usar ajax, ou vc apenas quer gravar o arquivo e a categoria no banco?

Comment: Eu preciso gravar o arquivo do upload e a respectiva categoria no banco. A maneira como será feito isso, não é o ponto principal. Em último caso, colocarei uma combobox na lista dos arquivos que o usuário fez o upload e um botão para fazer uma alteração no registro, inserindo a categoria.

Answer (score 0):

@Allan eu faço dessa forma, aí você adapta para seu código.

formulario.php

```
<form action="insere.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="cat">
<?php
//conexão
include 'conect.php';
//seleciona as categorias
$sql = "select nome_carac from carac where nome_carac is not null";
$exec = $con->query( $sql ) or exit( $con->error );                      
$i = 1;
while ( $f = $exec->fetch_object() )
{
$cats[$i]['nome_carac'] = $f->nome_carac;
$i++;
}
//gera a lista de opcoes
foreach ($cats as $key => $value) {
echo "<option value='{$value['nome_carac']}' > {$value['nome_carac']}</option></br>";
}
$con->close();
?>
</select></br>

<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>

<input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

insere.php

```
include 'conect.php';
// muda o banco "teste"
mysqli_select_db($con,"test_stack");
//trata imagem
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
//pega as informacoes das imagens
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='Tamanho máximo do arquivo : 2 MB';
    }

$select_opt =  $_POST['cat'];

$sql="INSERT INTO _stack (nome_img, nome_cat) VALUES ('$file_name','$select_opt ')";

    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);// Cria o diretorio para imagens
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //Renomeia se existe
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysqli_query($con, $sql);          
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
$con->close();
```

Repara que eu estou inserindo só o nome das imagens e a categoria que vem do select. Vê se ajuda qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta.